# Handling textures and multiple resolutions in libdgx

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

After trying out various options I've decided to ship my game with several different sets of images for different resolutions. When loading the game the device will pick the most appropriate set based on resolution then scale accordingly to to fine tune the image sizes.

code as follows:

```
private static Texture loadTexture(String filename, float width,
        float height) {

    // load our image
    Pixmap image = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.getFileHandle(imageFolder
            + filename, FileType.Internal));

    // create a new pixmap the size that we want our final image
    Pixmap scaledImage = new Pixmap((int) (screenWidth * width),
            (int) (screenHeight * height), Format.RGBA8888);

    // draw and scale the existing image to our new image
    scaledImage.drawPixmap(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight(), 0, 0, scaledImage.getWidth(),
            scaledImage.getHeight());

    // create a texture from our new image
    Texture texture = new Texture(scaledImage);

    // tidy up
    image.dispose();
    scaledImage.dispose();
    disposeList.add(texture);

    return texture;
}
```

The down side of this approach is that I can't pre-create texture atlases to be loaded when the game starts up.

As I understand it (with my limited knowledge of OpenGL), there is a performance boost from using a texture atlas, as the atlas is bound once, and then all textures are rendered from that single atlas. If I have separate textures for each image, then each one will have to be bound individually.

Would you advise that after resizing I add my textures to a new texture atlas at runtime when my game loads? I can then do my rendering using regions from that? If so, how do I detect the max atlas size on any given GPU using libgdx?

Comment: Why don't you create your texture atlasses offline (with the libgdx TexturePacker tool) with different resolutions? And in your code you load the assets that work best with the resolution? Also, you could use AssetManager for that to load all the stuff asynchronously, without blocking the UI thread.

Comment: @evident Because it's hard to account for all possible resolutions beforehand. I've got my own asynchronous asset loader already that gives me a bit more control.